# threading in someone else's address space

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

I'm building a monitor app and am having some threading issues.

I have, using  a cbt hook, injected a dll in to another processes memory.  I am reading the memory of the other application at certain addresses.  The trouble is I was using a loop to watch the process and basically the app being watched wasn't free to carry on.  So I thought put my watch process in a thread.  I am using the code below to create the thread:

```
void readAddresses(DWORD addr)
{
LPDWORD dwThreadID;
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadProc,&addr,0,dwThreadID);
}
```

I did try with CreateRemoteThread(...) as well and got the same error.  With the thread running when it calls the ReadProcessMemory() api it fails and i am not really sure what I am doing wrong.

```
//going to pass in an address, dword
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
 DWORD pid;
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(targetWindow,&pid);
 HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | 
                         PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                         FALSE, pid);

...
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(void *)_start, data, 255, &lpRead);
...
```

}

The trouble is when I call readprocessmemory I now get an access violation.  What I am curious about is that is the thread operating in the same process address space as the process into which it been injected.  As I said without the thread code it works fine but i need the monitor code to run in the background and i am wondering how to achieve this?  Should I use create remote thread?

As Remus sais use beginthread() or beginthreadex()...

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you call `ReadProcessMemory` as well what process handle you are using?

Comment: See @Remus Rusanu's answer, that pretty much explains your problem. Also, since your thread is already running in the other process' context, you can simply use `GetCurrentProcess` instead of `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `OpenProcess`.

Comment: Yes, after some more tests I do see that the valid dword addr is becomming garbled by my attempts to pass it as a LPVOID, do you have any suggestions as to how I can pass this value into the thread function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is sure: addresses to read and write are definitely not a `DWORD` type. From the code above, it seems that you pass an `DWORD addr` as the *address* to read from, then you start a thread to which you pass on the **address of your local `addr` parameter**. Most likely the thread proc is then attempting to read the address where the `addr` parameter *once was* in the current process on the original thread stack (a meaningless address now in *any* process) and the result is random (sometimes you will hit jackpot and read some innocent victim location on the remote process).

- pass in the address to read as a proper address (LPVOID). DWORD *cannot* be right.
- pass to the background thread *the address you want to read*, not some local stack frame garbage it cannot use

.

```
void readAddresses(LPVOID addr)
{
LPDWORD dwThreadID;
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,myThreadProc,addr,0,dwThreadID);
}

DWORD WINAPI myThreadProc(LPVOID addr)
{
   ...
    ReadProcessMemory (..., addr);
}
```

Comment: Actually DWORD is correct and that is the value being passed from managed code into the .dll.  The address is correct but my attempts to pass it into the thread as an LPVOID is what is causing the addr value to become garbage.  Do you have a suggestion as to how I could pass a value which is a valid address as a dword into the thread function?

Comment: No, `DWORD` is not correct. Managed code passes an 'address' as `IntPtr` to a the native DLL entry point that accepts a LPVOID parameter.

Comment: Ok Remus.  So I have taken out all the passing problems and have simply hard coded the correct address into the thread.  This address is valid and works correctly with ReadProcessMemory and returns the correct value from memory.  However, when I run the thread the address returns junk.  I am getting the address from a hex dump, for example 0x07AC9DE4.

Comment: Post the exact code, not a description. If you simply assigned `addr` with the value 0x07AC9DE4 and then invoked the thread the same way as in your post, then everything I said in my response still stands and you solved nothing. As a side note, I hope you are aware that there are x64 machines out there, are you?

Comment: Yes I am remus, just trying to learn c++ i'm sorry if that seems to offend you in some way.  And it does seem a little strange when you read books by hoglund and richter and they use dword values when looking at address space.

Comment: Make sure you do not pass `&addr` to CreateThread. That is the address of a *local parameter*. It has no meaning as soon as the call to `readAddresses` completes, that will be sooner than when the started thread reads it. Make `addr` an `LPVOID` and pass `CreateThread(...,addr,...)`. And if your C++ program uses CRT, you must use `beginthreadex` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to beginthreadex and everything worked.  Funnily enough I was also reading the chapter on threading in richter windows via c++ and there it was 'use beginthread...'  It's awesome when you know how.